# Simple code for request url and show response code | javascript | jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, request

How can to request url or website address and show response code with javascript or jquery?

i.e

```
request www.google.com
if (response_code = 200) {
print "website alive"
} else if (response_code = 204) {
print "not found";
}
```

Comment: From JavaScript in the browser? You'll hit [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from the `jquery` tag that you mean to do this in a browser, not from a server running NodeJS or similar (although there is a NodeJS module for jQuery).

Although you can request URLs and see the response code using the `XMLHttpRequest` object, the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will prevent your accessing virtually any sites other than the one the page itself was loaded from. But if you're pinging the server your page was loaded from to make sure it's still there, you can do that:

```
function ping(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
    xhr.open("get", url);
    xhr.send();

    function handleStateChange() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) { // Request is complete
            callback(xhr.status);   // Tell the callback what the status code is
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not sure understand but when i make document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = xhr.status; output is 0, why not status 200 or 204?

Comment: @user3142044: That usually means you've tried to request something that the SOP prevents you from getting.